# SELECT dentro de un WHILE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, while

Poseo el siguiente codigo

```
 $sql ="SELECT * FROM `monto_recarga` WHERE mod (monto, $multiplo) = 0";
 $resultadosql = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $num_datos = mysqli_num_rows($resultadosql);
 while ($rowsql=mysqli_fetch_row($resultadosql)){

  if($num_datos ==1)
  {
     $montos = $montos . "y " . $rowsql[1] . " Bs.";
  }
  else
  {
     $montos = $montos . $rowsql[1] . " Bs., ";
  }
     $num_datos--;
 }
```

Ese codigo lo estoy corriendo dentro de un WHILE, la variable `$multiplo` la asigna la function `selector_operador()` ya verifique y si esta dando la asignacion del valor a dicha variable, pero el resultado de la primera vuelta del ciclo es acumulada en la segunda vuelta y en la tercera etc etc..!!!

El codigo completo donde estoy intentando correr este selector segun el multiplo es el siguiente:

```
$counter = 1;

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

      $id = $row['id'];
       $titulo = $row['descripcion'];
        $contenido = $row['contenido'];
        $operador = $row['operador'];
        $monto = $row['monto'];

        selector_operador();



 $sql ="SELECT * FROM `monto_recarga` WHERE mod (monto, $multiplo) = 0";
 $resultadosql = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $num_datos = mysqli_num_rows($resultadosql);
 while ($rowsql=mysqli_fetch_row($resultadosql)){

  if($num_datos ==1)
  {
     $montos = $montos . "y " . $rowsql[1] . " Bs.";
  }
  else
  {
     //printf ("%s\nBs.\n", $rowsql[1]);
     $montos = $montos . $rowsql[1] . " Bs., ";
  }

     $num_datos--;
 }

        $po .= '
        <div class="card">
          '.$img_card.'
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title text-uppercase">Operadora '.$operador.'</h5>
            <p class="card-text">'.$contenido.'</p>
            <p class="card-text">
            Este servicio tiene un costo mensual de <b> '.$monto.' Bs</b></p>
            <p class="card-text">
            Y Puede efectuar recargas a cada numero '.$operador.' por: '.$montos.'
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted"> '.$link.'</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      ';



$counter++;
    }
```

El resultado obtenido es casi el que requiero, pero este repite en el segundo ciclo el resultado que dejo en la primera vuelta.
Es decir si en la primera vuelta la salida segun la variable `$multiplo` era:
`300 600 900` y para la segunda vuelta la salida tenia que ser `500 1000 1500` entonces en la salida obtengo en el primer caso la salida es la correcta `300 600 900` pero para la segunda vuelta del ciclo me da el siguiente resultado `300 600 900 500 1000 1500` como puedo hacer para que el codigo que poseo puedo evite que en cada vuelta se acumule el resultado anterior?

Comment: La variable multiplo sera la variable montos? para que contas los registros, si despues igual haces el while. Hay algo de tu logica que no entiendo, de donde salen esos numeros?

Comment: Dentro de la function selector_operador();
la variable $multiplo me permite con un solo numero seleccionar solo los valores que una operadora permite, ejemplo hay operadoras que permiten solo multiplos de 300 y otras solo multiplos de 5000 por ejemplo.

Comment: la variable $num_datos me permite conocer si hay mas de un valor en mi base de datos para darle un tratamiento al resultado de forma mas estetica, ejemplo en vez de hacer una salida 300 600 900 la salida es 300 Bs, 600 Bs y 900 Bs

Comment: Ok. ahi entendi un poco mejor tu problema. Ahora, si esta trayendo cosas de mas, es que tu query las esta trayendo.No hay forma que traiga 500 si hace mod(1000,300). Entonces hay que verificar ese query.

Comment: El query lo uso en otra parte dentro de una etiqueta select y si funciona perfectamente en el caso de mod 500 solo muestra los multiplos de 500 y en el caso de mod 100 muestra todos los multiplos de 100..! pero al tratar de implementar la misma logica en mi codigo expuesto acumula los resultados..!